# How to create a withdraw function

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I created a basic contract for crowdfunding. But cannot figure out how to create a withdraw function.

Withdraw function will transfer a campaign's collected funds to the campaign's owner. This is my full crowdfunding contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract CrowdFunding {
    event testConditon(
        uint256 deadline,
        uint256 currentTimeInMs,
        uint256 diff,
        bool condition
    );

    struct Campaign {
        address payable owner;
        string title;
        string description;
        uint256 target;
        uint256 deadline;
        uint256 amountCollected;
        string image;
        address[] donators;
        uint256[] donations;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => Campaign) public campaigns;

    uint256 public numberOfCampaigns = 0;

    function createCampaign(
        address _owner,
        string memory _title,
        string memory _description,
        uint256 _target,
        uint256 _deadline,
        string memory _image
    ) public returns (uint256) {
        Campaign storage campaign = campaigns[numberOfCampaigns];
        uint256 currentTimeInMs = block.timestamp * 1000;

        emit testConditon(
            _deadline,
            currentTimeInMs,
            _deadline - currentTimeInMs,
            _deadline > currentTimeInMs
        );

        require(
            _deadline > currentTimeInMs,
            "The deadline must be in the future"
        );

        campaign.owner = payable(_owner);
        campaign.title = _title;
        campaign.description = _description;
        campaign.target = _target;
        campaign.deadline = _deadline;
        campaign.image = _image;
        campaign.amountCollected = 0;

        numberOfCampaigns++;

        return numberOfCampaigns - 1;
    }

    function donateToCampaign(uint256 _id) public payable {
        uint256 amount = msg.value;

        Campaign storage campaign = campaigns[_id];

        campaign.donators.push(msg.sender);
        campaign.donations.push(amount);

        (bool sent, ) = payable(campaign.owner).call{value: amount}("");

        if (sent) {
            campaign.amountCollected += amount;
        }
    }

    function getDonators(uint256 _id)
        public
        view
        returns (address[] memory, uint256[] memory)
    {
        return (campaigns[_id].donators, campaigns[_id].donations);
    }

    function getCampaigns() public view returns (Campaign[] memory) {
        Campaign[] memory allCampaigns = new Campaign[](numberOfCampaigns);

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < numberOfCampaigns; i++) {
            Campaign storage item = campaigns[i];
            allCampaigns[i] = item;
        }

        return allCampaigns;
    }

    function withdraw(uint256 _id) public {
        Campaign storage campaign = campaigns[_id];

        require(
            campaign.amountCollected >= campaign.target,
            "The campaign has not reached its target"
        );

        //deadline has passed
        // require(
        //     campaign.deadline < block.timestamp * 1000,
        //     "The deadline has not passed yet"
        // );

        require(
            campaign.owner == msg.sender,
            "Only the owner of the campaign can withdraw the funds"
        );

        campaign.owner.transfer(campaign.amountCollected);
        campaign.amountCollected = 0;
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to solve this issue.

Comment: Withdraw function might be `payable`?

Comment: Is the logic accurate in withdraw function?

Comment: Inside the function, it is accurate. See my edited answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the `payable` keyword to trigger the token transfer. Try this:

```
function withdraw(uint256 _id) public {
  Campaign storage campaign = campaigns[_id];

  (bool success, ) = payable(campaign.owner).call{value: campaign.amountCollected}("");
  require(success, "Withdrawal failure");
  campaign.amountCollected = 0;
}
```

**Warning**: this function and your function are having a reentrency vulnerability.

Comment: It's not working. It is showing `{
    "code": -32603,
    "message": "execution reverted: Withdrawal failure",
    "data": {
        "originalError": {
            "code": 3,
            "data": "0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000125769746864726177616c206661696c7572650000000000000000000000000000",
            "message": "execution reverted: Withdrawal failure"
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Do you have enough token to pay the gas fees?

Comment: How can I check how many tokens I have? Btw I can easily donate to a campaign through metamask.

Comment: What chain are you using? You may use a wallet provider like `MetaMask` to see how many token you are owning

Comment: I am using MetaMask, to donate to a campaign.

Comment: By the way, it’s your contract that must have some ETH (for exemple) because it will support the transfert gaz fees

Comment: Does not the donated amount(ETH) get added to the contract? Like, the donated amount gets added to the contract, and then when I withdraw it, will be sent to the campaign owner.

Comment: Can you see any ETH on etherscan on your deployed contract address?

Comment: I have deployed my contract to `thirdweb`.  This is my contact [link](https://thirdweb.com/goerli/0xa2f8e20918CF568a76E66cf1Da4Eb10DCbAE500F)

Comment: It's showing `Balance:
0 Ether`

Comment: That is how we can explain your error code: `-32603`

Comment: Does this mean the donation does not get added to the contract? What should I do now?

Comment: One more request, can you pls check my` donate to campaign` function?  If it is correct, then should the donation get added to the contract?